# How to use the function exec to start a login shell(csh)?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have already known that I can use the parameter `-l` to start a `bash` or `ksh` as a login shell, so I don't have to source the files like `~/.profile`,`~/.bash_profile` and so on. But in `csh`,the sentence

```
execl("/bin/csh","csh","-l","-c","env",NULL);
```

is wrong, the wrong information is

```
Unknown option: `-l'
```

but I looked up the [csh man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) and find that `-l` means

> "The shell is a login shell. Applicable only if `-l` is the only flag specified.".

So I changed the sentence to

```
execl("/bin/csh","csh","-l",NULL);
```

and

```
execl("/bin/csh","csh","-c","env",NULL);
```

but when I run the program, it suspended there. Could you please tell me how to solve it？

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *it suspended there*. The process does not exit? What is the state of the process? What is on the file descriptors (`ls /proc/$PID/fd`)? Which of of the last two `execl()` calls is showing the problem?

Comment: I have to use ctrl+c to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it this way instead:

```
execl("/bin/sh","sh","-l","-c","exec csh -l",NULL);
```

By the way, how did you know that `-l` for other shells was the solution? ;)

Comment: It just reminds me of your previous thread. :) I hope this one helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the actual environment a logged in user gets, you'll need to log in the user. PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) can and do set environment variables at login time, and just executing a shell will not trigger those.

One approach is to create a pseudoterminal, and run `/bin/login -f username` (with root privileges, with standard streams opened to the slave pseudoterminal) to login the specified user. `-f username` should tell `login` that the user is preauthenticated, so no password dialog should be presented. Everything written to the master pseudoterminal acts as if the user had input it; reading from the master pseudoterminal obtains the input (as input is normally echoed to terminal) as well as the results.

The difficulty is that you *must* read and write to the pseudoterminal concurrently; there is absolutely no reliable order you can use. (You'll need to write the commands you wish to run as the user to the pseudoterminal master, and read the resulting outputs.) Furthermore, there is no simple way to know when the shell commands are completed; it is completely asynchronous.

You cannot reliably reconstruct an environment using `env`, because environment variables can contain newlines, and `env` does not escape them in any way. So, you probably should use a helper executable instead. (Environment name-value pairs can contain everything except ASCII NULs `\0`, so outputting all environment name-value pairs with NUL separators will work; the Linux kernel also provides `/proc/self/environ` in exactly that format.)

If your parent process generates a temporary file name, and supply a command that executes the helper that writes the NUL-separated environment name-value pairs to the specified file, e.g. `"/usr/local/bin/envpairs0 /tmp/tempfile \n logout \n "`, you know the task is done when the child process exits. Then you just clean up the pseudoterminal, and read and delete the temporary file containing the environment for that user.

As you can see, this is quite complex. It is somewhat simpler in scripting languages such as Python that have pseudoterminal support (see `pty` Python module for example). Not knowing what you need the user environments for -- and especially whether this is a one-off occurrence, or needed on a regular basis --, it is difficult for me to give any better advice.

I could show you an example program on how to achieve this, but I'm a bit wary due to the apparent hostility here to such complex and long examples. Perhaps you should consider a simpler approach to achieve your objectives?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The situation is that I have a process A which is started as root, as user might switch account，so the current user is uncertain. Process A now need to use the current user's environment variables to fork a new process B, so I have to fork a process C to get the environment variables and transmit them to process A, so A can use these variables to fork B.This is what I want to do ? Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: @BreakingDawn: *"as user might switch account"* -- how? Perhaps you might wish to split your service into two parts: the privileged part that runs as root, and a tracking/unprivileged part that the user starts (or is started automatically by the user profile). Or you can track user processes, and snoop their environment from `/proc/PID/environ`. Or you can make your process a full-fledged service similar to `sshd`, making it PAM-aware.. More details might help. What is the purpose?

Comment: Just use "su" to switch account,but the running process A is started by root.Process A want to use the current user's environment variables to fork a new Process B.

Comment: *What is current user?* There can be any number of users logged in on a machine, some from console, some remotely, some over SSH, even if using a desktop environment (via X11 forwarding). It does sound like tracking the process the user controls, and using its `/proc/PID/environ`, might be the simplest option.

Comment: @BreakingDawn: Do you know the process or processes the tracked user controls?

Comment: You can assume that we have got the current username.

Comment: @BreakingDawn: Are you sure you really need the exact user environment? I did write an example program that does it (uses a pseudoterminal to login the user preauthenticated, then runs `dd if=/proc/self/environ of=temporary-file` and logs out the user, returning the environment variables as a dynamically allocated array of pointers); it's just that *I don't think it is a sane approach*. That is, other services work fine with a basic/minimal environment.

Comment: Yes,I am sure of that. I just want to get the current user's environment variables instead of source the files.